# Varnish with multiple sites and multiple IPs

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, multisite

I am trying to run Varnish for two domains and each of them on different IP, and configured with its own .VCL file.
I succeeded in writing all config files, so that Varnish will listen on each IP; so that Apache will listen for Varnish on two ports.
Everything looks great, BUT!
When I load first domain in browser, it forwards (302) to second domain.
My previous setup was working as first domain to work without Varnish and second domain with Varnish.
Can anybody suggest solution or debugging approach.
10x

Comment: Sounds like you are overcomplicating things. Why configure Varnish to listen on different IPs? You need two backend definitions in Varnish (not listen), for each IP of your backend server. If you get redirect it looks like everything is on a single server :D then simply setup one backend 127.0.0.1 and do conditional VCL inclusion based on value of HTTP host variable https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/varnish/varnish-virtual-hosts

Comment: Two IPs are on purpose! Under " conditional VCL inclusion" you mean placing Ifs (req.http.host) in every sub using one .vcl file? That complicates things since each domain uses different rules under wordpress. First domain has a login and js forms that do not work well under Varnish, so I try to keep two different .vcl to make it easier for configuring and debugging. In case there three domains one .vlc-default will even be more complicated.
I already have two backends listening on each IP, but one redirects to the second.

Comment: Under earlier versions of Varnish on CentoS it was much easier to make the same setup. Now I am trying to do the same with Varnish 4 on Debian and face few misconceptions. Do I have to run a second instance of varnish for second domain???

Comment: Sounds like you haven't read the article at all. By conditional VCL inclusion I mean placing ifs in SEPARATE file per each domain. It is very elegant and straightforward if you try to understand how it's done and how VCL inclusion works in Varnish.

Comment: @DanielV. Thanks for the link. I did view it. Now I'read it few more times. First it has a mistake, because you dont but subroutines in a .conf files. However, maybe it doesnt matter when done via include.
Second, it rises a major question. Since Varnish executes all subroutines in orderly fashion, how the included .vcl per domain files at the end of the "head" vcl file, their subroutines will be executed after, for example sub vcl_hit, in the "head" vcl?

Comment: Anyway, I did solved the forwarding mystery and have found some debugging practices.

Answer (score 0):

I have this setup working without issues. I am using one vcl file (logic on both sites/backends is almost the same). Server has multiple ip's, apache uses them all, and it servers different sites on different ip's. Some of ip's have virtualhosts on them as well.

First, check if your Apache installation is valid and that there are no redirects.

```
curl -I -L http://hostname1.com
```

Second, in your vcl, define backends (first example is if backend1 is virtualhost, example2 is if backend2 is not vhost and is accessible at this ip)

```
backend backend1 {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "81";
    .host_header = "hostname1.com";
}

backend backend2 {
  .host = "192.168.1.1";
  .port = "80";
}
```

Third, in you vcl_recv you will have something like this:

```
  if (req.http.host ~ "^(www\.)?hostname1\.com$") {
    set req.http.host = "hostname1.com";
    set req.backend_hint = backend1;

  }
  elseif (req.http.host ~ "^(www\.)?hostname2\.com$") {
    set req.http.host = "hostname2.com";
    set req.backend_hint = backend2;
  }
```

That's it.